# Is there a way to clear all innerHTML's?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

As title states, I'm wondering if it is possible to clear every innerHTML changed with javascript.

For instance if I have 20 functions that each replaced the innerHTML of a `p-tag`, can I make them all contain nothing (with the click of a button) without changing .innerHTML on each and every one of them?

```
function resetAll() {
  outputOne.innerHTML = "";
  outputTwoA.innerHTML = "";
  outputTwoB.innerHTML = "";
  outputThreeA.innerHTML = "";
  outputThreeB.innerHTML = "";
  outputThreeC.innerHTML = "";
}
```

This is an example of what I don't want to do.

I know I can refresh the page, but that's not the solution I'm asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just javascript you would need to loop over all of them. You could do this with a common class:

```
var clearUs = document.querySelectorAll('.common-class');
var index = 0, length = clearUs.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    clearUs[index].innerHTML = '';
}
```

If you want to use something like jquery its less code but still a loop happening in background you just don't need to see or type it:

```
$('.common-class').html('');
```

Comment: Exact what I was writing." can I make them all contain nothing (with the click of a button) without changing .innerHTML on each and every one of them? " A: No. Do as AtheistP3ace in plain JS or one line with jQuery

Comment: upvote for showing the jQuery AND plain javascript answers. Nice.

Comment: I'm afraid this will have unintended consequences. If you have any nested elements, such as `<div><div></div></div>`, you will lose them.  http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/5x24e36b/

Answer (score 0):

Create a class, set on p tag and select all by this class and run a for cleaning all.

Answer (score 0):

Just cache in your change method which elements you changed, and then loop over the changed array and clear the innerHTML there.

You could ofcourse still check if the changed array already contains the element you are pushing in, but for an example, I thought this is enough

```js
var changed = [];

function change(pIndex, text) {
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
  if (!all || !all[pIndex]) {
    // element not found
    return;
  }
  all[pIndex].innerHTML = text;
  changed.push(all[pIndex]);
}

function clearAll() {
  for (var i = 0, len = changed.length; i < len; i++) {
    changed[i].innerHTML = '';
  }
  changed.splice(0, changed.length);
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<button onclick="change(0, 'test')" type="button">Set p 1</button>
<button onclick="change(1, 'test')" type="button">Set p 1</button>
<button onclick="change(2, 'test')" type="button">Set p 1</button>
<button onclick="clearAll();" type="button">Clear</button>
```